# How to make use of BlackWidow?

Tags: webserver, wifi, arduino

I have got [BlackWidow](http://asynclabs.com/wiki/index.php?title=BlackWidow_1.0) now.

I have downloaded the WiShield library, and I am using the web server example code to study it.

But I have following queries:

- What does this example code do?
- Where can I see that web server?
- How can I connect my blackwidow to my Wi-Fi?
- What is [SSID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_set_%28802.11_network%29#Service_set_identifier_.28SSID.29)?

/*
 * Web Server
 *
 * A simple web server example using the WiShield 1.0
 */

```
include <WiShield.h>

define WIRELESS_MODE_INFRA  1
define WIRELESS_MODE_ADHOC  2

// Wireless configuration parameters ----------------------------------------
unsigned char local_ip[] = {192,168,1,2};   // IP address of WiShield
unsigned char gateway_ip[] = {192,168,1,1}; // router or gateway IP address
unsigned char subnet_mask[] = {255,255,255,0};  // subnet mask for the local network
const prog_char ssid[] PROGMEM = {"ASYNCLABS"};     // max 32 bytes

unsigned char security_type = 0;    // 0 - open; 1 - WEP; 2 - WPA; 3 - WPA2

// WPA/WPA2 passphrase
//const prog_char security_passphrase[] PROGMEM = {"12345678"}; // max 64 characters
const prog_char security_passphrase[] PROGMEM = {"9953395712"}; 
// WEP 128-bit keys
// sample HEX keys
prog_uchar wep_keys[] PROGMEM = {   0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d,   // Key 0
                                    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,   // Key 1
                                    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,   // Key 2
                                    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00    // Key 3
                                };

// setup the wireless mode
// infrastructure - connect to AP
// adhoc - connect to another WiFi device
unsigned char wireless_mode = WIRELESS_MODE_INFRA;

unsigned char ssid_len;
unsigned char security_passphrase_len;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void setup()
{
    WiFi.init();
}

// This is the webpage that is served up by the webserver
const prog_char webpage[] PROGMEM = {"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<center><h1>Hello World!! I am WiShield</h1><form method=\"get\" action=\"0\">Toggle LED:<input type=\"submit\" name=\"0\" value=\"LED1\"></input></form></center>"};

void loop()
{
    WiFi.run();
}
```

What does this code do?

Comment: how to even turn on the wifi ??

Comment: adhoc network?? if there is some ebook explaining all this?

Comment: my wifi connection status led never lights up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [BlackWidow forum](http://asynclabs.com/forums/viewforum.php?f=21)
- [WiShield forum](http://asynclabs.com/forums/viewforum.php?f=23)

FYI: AsyncLabs announced they were closing their doors.  The forums will remain open.

Comment: you mean to say i cant connect android and blackwidow??

Comment: Correct, this is an iPhone tool.  The code you posted is objective c and used by Apple for development.  Android uses Java.

Comment: the code i posted was to create a network over arduino and make it a webserver. The server could be accessed by any wifi object in vicinity and hence either android, iphone or any other smartphone having wifi could be able to control the electric goods connected to blackwidow.. but my problem is that i am unable to create a network in black widow neither m i able to use INFRA mode to add it to another existing network... i just wanna once ping on the ip of the blackwidow through my laptop when both are connected by wifi or either modem...